# stuck with repeated section in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression on PHP but have gotten stuck with repeated section below. Is it possible to get this info with one regular expression?

With this group - `Grandma (2013/Bluray)`

```
<h1>Grandma / Nice story of grandma 2013 / Grandparents / Granma on vacation (2013/Bluray)</h1>
<h1>Grandma / Nice story of grandma 2013 / Grandparents (2013/Bluray)</h1>
<h1>Grandma / Nice story of grandma 2013 (2013/Bluray)</h1>
<h1>Grandma (2013/Bluray)</h1>
```

With this group - `Game of death 2 (1981/HDRip)`

```
<h1>Game of death 2 / TD 2 / Super death towers II / Towers of Death / Game of Death II / Tower of Death (1981/HDRip)</h1>
<h1>Game of death 2 / TD II / Super death towers II / Towers of Death / Game of Death II / Tower of Death (1981/HDRip)</h1>
<h1>Game of death 2 / Super death towers II / Towers of Death / Game of Death II / Tower of Death (1981/HDRip)</h1>
<h1>Game of death 2 / Towers of Death / Game of Death II / Tower of Death (1981/HDRip)</h1>
<h1>Game of death 2 / Towers of Death / Tower of Death (1981/HDRip)</h1>
<h1>Game of death 2 / Tower of Death (1981/HDRip)</h1>
```

The regex I have now is `/<h1>([^\/]*)(.*)\((.*)\)<\/h1>/i`. But it does not work on `<h1>Grandma (2013/Bluray)</h1>`.

Comment: What do you mean by "first group" and "second group"?  What are you trying to match?

Comment: as a result I need to get "Grandma (2013/Bluray)" and "Game of death 2 (1981/HDRip)"

Comment: @Danik [**why are you breaking your head with a regex when the string is separated by a `/` and the items u want are the first and last on the string ? use `explode` `$item[0]` and `array_pop`**](http://web.guicar.com/Php/Php-5/PHP%20array_pop%20-%20Manual.htm) Here is an easier regex [**`<h1>([\w\s]+)(\/.*|\s+)(\(.*\))<\/h1>`**](http://rubular.com/r/l4NbmikppG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t have access to a PHP regex engine to try this, but the following regex [works in .NET](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=19bbd709-48d0-47e7-916e-4d62fd3a9fbc):

```
<h1>([^\/(]*)(?:.*)\((.*)\)<\/h1>
```

That captures that data you want for all of your sample inputs. On [the live demo page](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=19bbd709-48d0-47e7-916e-4d62fd3a9fbc), click “20 groups” near the right to see the contents of the captured groups.

I changed two things from what you had:

- changed `[^\/]` to `[^\/(]` to avoid capturing what is in parentheses
- changed `(.*)` to `(?:.*)`, making it a non-capturing group, because we don’t care about that part of the text

This regex captures extra spaces in some cases, so you should call [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on the captured groups to get rid of the extra spaces.